# optimising vba - application.

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

This is not the most vital question and is more curisoity.
I use application.screenupdating etc etc in all of my subroutines.
I will typically have multiple modules and subroutines, all of which have the optimisation codes.

I want to know if there is a way to not have to write the codes in every single module?

I guess i am looking for a concept similar to that of globally declared variables that can be used in any module or subroutine, without having the define them each time

```
with application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
end with
```

Comment: You need to xlsb file, if you want to share the excel code or vbscript may also help you.

Comment: im sorry? i dont understand wht you mean...

Comment: This [example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/vba-class-to-persist-and-restore-excel-application-properties) uses classes to persist and restore Application settings. Or another [approach](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142793/applicationsettings-class-for-disabling-restoring-application-state) in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a boolean function, if the function is set to true then .ScreenUpdating is set to false and vice versa.

```
Public Function ApplicationOptimization(BOOLEAN_TRIGGER As Boolean)
With Application
    Select Case BOOLEAN_TRIGGER
    Case True
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Case False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End Select
End With
End Function

Public Sub Use()
ApplicationOptimization (False) 'False or True
End Sub
```

You can create this function in a single Module and then reference it in any other module or form. This should save repeating code in each Module. Apologies if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: whats the "not" part about?

Comment: The `not` sets passes the opposite value of `ApplicationOptimization()`. Therefore, if you set `ApplicationOptimization()` to true, the `.properties` are set to false.

Comment: You'd need to add an `IF` or `SELECT CASE` on the `ApplicationOptimization()` to capture the boolean value. When `ApplicationOptimization() = TRUE THEN .calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: errors with function call on left hand side of assignment must return vairant of objecgt

Comment: Apologies, I was busy at the time. I've updated the code to something you should be able to use. I've actually tested it this time and it works. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a code-shell generator. Add a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, and then:

```
Public Sub SubShell(SubName As String)
    Dim s As String
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

    s = "Sub " & SubName & "()" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(4, " ") & "With Application" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(8, " ") & ".ScreenUpdating = False" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(8, " ") & ".DisplayStatusBar = False" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(4, " ") & "End With" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(4, " ") & "'Insert Code" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(4, " ") & "With Application" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(8, " ") & ".ScreenUpdating = True" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(8, " ") & ".DisplayStatusBar = True" & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(4, " ") & "End With" & vbCrLf
    s = s & "End Sub" & vbCrLf
    DataObj.SetText s
    DataObj.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

If you now type `SubShell "Test"` in the immediate window, position your cursor where you want the sub and then paste, you will see the following appear:

```
Sub Test()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
    End With

    'Insert Code

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is neat! but not what i am trying to achieve unfortunately

Comment: Your question was about how to avoid boiler plate code. My suggestion doesn't avoid the boiler plate, but saves keystrokes by generating it automatically. I agree that it would be preferable to avoid the need for it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem changing application settings in code is that they overwrite user preferences - e.g. an end user normally has their Calculation set to manual for working with large workbooks but each time they run your code it is set back to automatic at the end.

To overcome this the subroutine below assigns current application settings to static variables and uses these to reset the application.

```
Private Sub optimise_execution(optimise As Boolean)
' Optimise / Reset application settings for running VBA code
Static calcStr As Variant
Static screenBool As Boolean, statusBool As Boolean, eventsBool As Boolean, displayBreaksBool As Boolean
        If Not optimise Then GoTo RestoreSettings
' Clean up variables
            calcStr = vbNullString: screenBool = False: statusBool = False: eventsBool = False: displayBreaksBool = False
StoreSettings:          ' Store the current application settings
            calcStr = Application.Calculation
            screenBool = Application.ScreenUpdating
            eventsBool = Application.EnableEvents
            displayBreaksBool = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
OptimiseSettings:       ' Set optimum settings
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Exit Sub
RestoreSettings:        ' Restore previous application settings
            Application.Calculation = calcStr
            Application.ScreenUpdating = screenBool
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
            Application.EnableEvents = eventsBool
            ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayBreaksBool
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Public Sub Main()
    Call optimise_execution(True)   ' True to optimise / False to reset
End Sub
```

Best regards, 
Doug C